# showing php hidden rows when passed to modal

Tags: php, ajax

I have an HTML table that has rows retrieved from database.

using `tbody` tag I hid some rows to show them in a modal and do some editing if necessary.
the modal works perfectly with editing in database and all but the data that supposed to be displayed for editing are hidden as well!

how to fix this?

here is my table with hidden rows code which are inside a while statement:

```
<tbody style="display:none">
<td data-target="FLOOR"><?php echo $row['FLOOR'];?></td>
<td data-target="ORDER_OFFICE"><?php echo $row['ORDER_OFFICE'];?></td>
<td data-target="SERIAL_NO"><?php echo $row['SERIAL_NO'];?></td>
<td data-target="POINT_NO"><?php echo $row['POINT_NO'];?></td>
<td data-target="NOTE"><?php echo $row['NOTE'];?></td>
<td data-target="OTHER_NAME"><?php echo $row['OTHER_NAME'];?></td>
<td data-target="ORDER_TELE"><?php echo $row['ORDER_TELE'];?></td>
</tbody>



 <script>  

    //  append values in input fields
      $(document).on('click','a[data-role=update]',function(){
            var id  = $(this).data('id');
            var FLOOR  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=FLOOR]').text();
            var ORDER_OFFICE  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=ORDER_OFFICE]').text();
            var SERIAL_NO  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=SERIAL_NO]').text();
            var POINT_NO  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=POINT_NO]').text();
            var NOTE  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=NOTE]').text();
            var OTHER_NAME  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=OTHER_NAME]').text();
            var ORDER_TELE  = $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=ORDER_TELE]').text();

            $('#FLOOR').val(FLOOR);
            $('#ORDER_OFFICE').val(ORDER_OFFICE);
            $('#SERIAL_NO').val(SERIAL_NO);
            $('#POINT_NO').val(POINT_NO);
            $('#NOTE').val(NOTE);
            $('#OTHER_NAME').val(OTHER_NAME);
            $('#ORDER_TELE').val(ORDER_TELE);
            $('#userId').val(id);
            $('#myModal3').modal({backdrop: "static"});
      });
       // now create event to get data from fields and update in database 

       $('#save').click(function(){
          var ID = $('#userId').val(); 
         var FLOOR =  $('#FLOOR').val();
          var ORDER_OFFICE =  $('#ORDER_OFFICE').val();
          var SERIAL_NO = $('#SERIAL_NO').val();
          var POINT_NO = $('#POINT_NO').val();
          var NOTE = $('#NOTE').val();
          var OTHER_NAME = $('#OTHER_NAME').val();
          var ORDER_TELE = $('#ORDER_TELE').val();

          $.ajax({
              url      : 'edit_order.php',
              method   : 'post', 
              data     : {FLOOR : FLOOR, ORDER_OFFICE : ORDER_OFFICE, SERIAL_NO : SERIAL_NO, POINT_NO : POINT_NO 
                        ,NOTE : NOTE, OTHER_NAME : OTHER_NAME, ORDER_TELE: ORDER_TELE, ID: ID},
              success  : function(response){
                            // now update user record in table 
                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=FLOOR]').text(FLOOR);
                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=ORDER_OFFICE]').text(ORDER_OFFICE);
                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=SERIAL_NO]').text(SERIAL_NO);
                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=POINT_NO]').text(POINT_NO);
                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=NOTE]').text(NOTE);
                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=OTHER_NAME]').text(OTHER_NAME);
                             $('#'+id).children('td[data-target=ORDER_TELE]').text(ORDER_TELE);
                             $('#myModal3').modal('toggle'); 

                         }
          });
       });
 });
 </script>
```

thank you.

Comment: Could you also show the javascript codes?

Comment: @HastaDhana edit the post just now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show this table for editing just delete `style="display:none"` from tbody tag by using javascript after you rendered page or if the condition you wait turn to **true**. I do not recommend to use style directly inside of tag if you want to change it conditionally. You can do it by using javascript.

Or you can **check if hide or not** when rendering on PHP side.

```
<tbody style="<?php echo $ifConditionTrue ? "display:none" : "";?>">'
```

Or short way

```
<tbody style="<?= $ifConditionTrue ? "display:none" : "";?>">'
```

Comment: sounds the right way to do it. but how to apply it on php side? or what is the right condition for JS?

Comment: In your code it seems like you add html inside php code. Therefore I showed the way if condition is true to show needed fields in modal. Other way you must do it inside javascript.